# issue in Html parsing in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I am using HTMLAGility Pack to parse HTML file as I want to access attributes of DIVS in HTML.

Following my code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load("C:\\sampleHtml.html");
var divs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");
List<Feature> pageTitles = new List<Feature>();
foreach (var div in divs)
{
    pageTitles.Add(new Feature(Convert.ToInt32(div.Id), div.Name.ToString(), false, false));
}
```

This is my HTML

```
<div id="101"  isEnabled="0">My Binders<br />
<img align="" width="170" vspace="0" hspace="0" height="113" border="0" alt="" src="http://www.obout.com/editor_new/images/Nature/field_from_woods.jpg" title="" /><br />
<div id="111" isEnabled="0">Share Binders<br />
<img align="" width="170" vspace="0" hspace="0" height="114" border="0" alt="" src="http://www.obout.com/editor_new/images/Nature/meadow_cows.jpg" title="" /><br />
</div>
<div id="123" isEnabled="0">Add Binders<br />
<img align="" width="48" vspace="0" hspace="0" height="48" border="0" alt="" src="http://www.obout.com/editor_new/images/flags/shadow/flag_american_samoa.png" title="" /><br />
</div></div>
```

I have a "IsEnabled" property for each div. But, I am not able to access the value of this property using HTMLAgile pack. How can this be achieved.

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to access the value of `isEnabled` property?

Comment: var divs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"); gives a list of DIV's in which I get all properties, but not the userdefined ones.      Or else, I tried , var list = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div@IsEnabled");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in a sample Console Application:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\sampleHtml.html");
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.GetAttributeValue("isEnabled", null));
}
```

will dump all the value of the `isEnabled` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not possible to add custom attributes to elements.
They won't be parsed.

In HTML5 you can use the `data-attributes`:

```
<div data-Enabled="0">..</div>
```

Comment: If i use data-attributes of HTML5, will they be parsed in C#

Comment: I did some researc: Html Agility Pack should be able to parse HTML5 without any problems, so long as a logical structure expected of valid HTML is provided

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class CustomAttributesParser
{
    private static HtmlDocument BuildHtmlDocument()
    {
        string html = @"<div id=""101""  isEnabled=""0"">My Binders<br />
                        <img align="""" width=""170"" vspace=""0"" hspace=""0"" height=""113"" border=""0"" alt="""" src=""http://www.obout.com/editor_new/images/Nature/field_from_woods.jpg"" title="""" /><br />
                        <div id=""111"" isEnabled=""0"">Share Binders<br />
                        <img align="""" width=""170"" vspace=""0"" hspace=""0"" height=""114"" border=""0"" alt="""" src=""http://www.obout.com/editor_new/images/Nature/meadow_cows.jpg"" title="""" /><br />
                        </div>
                        <div id=""123"" isEnabled=""0"">Add Binders<br />
                        <img align="""" width=""48"" vspace=""0"" hspace=""0"" height=""48"" border=""0"" alt="""" src=""http://www.obout.com/editor_new/images/flags/shadow/flag_american_samoa.png"" title="""" /><br />
                        </div></div>";
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        return doc;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<string> Parse()
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = BuildHtmlDocument();
        var divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");
        if (divs != null)
        {
            return divs.Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("isEnabled", String.Empty));
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parser = new CustomAttributesParser();
        parser.Parse()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```